# cropping the zoomed image in windows phone using the "Image Recipes" official sample

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I found this great official sample for pinching and zooming images, here :
[Image Recipes](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/image-recipes-0c0b8fee)
I have changed the dimensions of the viewport to my desired size(say 300x300). now suppose I have zoomed the image to the desired state and need to crop it(and save the cropped image,as it's seen after zooming inside the viewport).
how could I do that? 
please advise.

Comment: I advise you to try it.

Comment: try it?I've been playing around it for over 2 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, since I didn't get any response here, I came up with this idea to place another canvas behind the viewportcontrol and render it to a wrtiteablebitmap .
this is working quite well.